# Why is 'xattr' not working?

Tags: terminal, filesystem, python, utilities, darwin

When I attempt to execute `xattr` in Terminal, I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/xattr-2.7", line 33, in <module>
    import xattr
ImportError: No module named xattr
```

What's going on here? I thought xattr [was part of Darwin](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xattr.1.html). Is `xattr` written in Python? Does it require a Python package to be installed on my system?

Comment: xattr is part of OSX and does use python but all the correct bits should be there - have you installed or deleted any python - also which OS verso are you on?

Comment: Does `ls /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/xattr` find anything? That's where the xattr module should be (at least in Mavericks). It should contain _xattr.so and several .py and .pyc files.

Comment: @Mark: That will do as an answer. The core of the question is whether it's a Python package, which I gather it is. (Simply installing it fixes the issue.)

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius How did you install it - it should not be needed - I would reinstall the OS

Comment: @Mark: Don't worry about it. I has to do with my Python installation, which is fine. The question is simply whether it has a Python dependency.

Comment: Be advised if you install the python version of `xattr` sometimes it will complain when calling `xattr` directly via terminal.   https://stackoverflow.com/a/58616002/1896134

and the xattr can have multiple versions outside of python. https://stackoverflow.com/a/57445635/1896134

Comment: also here is some sample code examples of how i ended up using it FWIW: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57724756/1896134

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The file that is executed when you run the command xattr is `/usr/bin/xattr` which is a python script that works out what version of python you have and then executes /usr/bin/xattr-2.7 for python 2.7. This script is also python and includes a `import xattr` to import the python module xattr from the Apple installed python libraries

Comment: In my macOS 13.2 installation, the `/usr/bin/xattr` executable is now a native executable, not a Python script.

Answer (score 5):

Might want to add some newer info per 2023:

The `xattr` executable shipped with macOS 13.2 is no longer a Python script, but a native binary, so the original issue should no longer be possible:

```
$ file /usr/bin/xattr
/usr/bin/xattr: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures: [x86_64:Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64] [arm64e:Mach-O 64-bit executable arm64e]
/usr/bin/xattr (for architecture x86_64):   Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
/usr/bin/xattr (for architecture arm64e):   Mach-O 64-bit executable arm64e
```

But ... the [Python `xattr` package](https://pypi.org/project/xattr/) still provides a similar command that might cause issues if installed in the same system and made available on the `PATH` as it does not share the same set of options! This can happen with Homebrew for instance (where it lands in `/opt/homebrew/bin/xattr`, shadowing the built-in). The executable is just a small script that calls out to the main module:

```
#!/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.10/bin/python3.10
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys
from xattr.tool import main
if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(main())
```

Comment: For me `file /usr/bin/xattr` gives `/usr/bin/xattr: Python script text executable, ASCII text`. What can I do to use the native binary you mention but still have access to my Python(s)?

Comment: Which version of macOS are you running? I am running macOS 13.2

Comment: ping @orome. would be useful to know more about your OS.

Comment: Mine now corresponds to what you have, following a recent migration to macOS 13.2. (The question applies to the old Big Sur / Intel system.)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a version of Python installed with Homebrew, try unlinking it.

```
brew unlink python
```

`/usr/local/bin/xattr` uses the version of Python 3 suggested to it by `env`. Brew overrides this, but does not include the xattr library, causing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Was your `/Library/Python/2.7` directory deleted by any chance? Some scripts look for `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Extras.pth`.

On my Mac, this file contains a couple of lines:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC
```

xattr itself is in the first directory above. I faced the same problem today and realized I'd inadvertently deleted `/Library/Python/2.7` earlier today thinking it was something else. Xattr went nuts, restoring this directory fixed it.

Comment: This might well be correct but is not an answer and has been suggested in the comments. Th op says that they had messed around with their python setup and knows all this

Comment: Explaining *how* the directory can be restored would make this more helpful for others with the same issue.